# How to disable plotly express from grouping bars based on color?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns: name, group, value. I wanted to make a horizontal bar chart with plotly that is sorted from highest to lowest value and color each bar based on their value in the group column. The problem is that when I add the color argument, the bars get sorted by the colors as well. Is it possible to make the bars not get grouped together by color?

Here is what I have tried. When I run the code without specifying the color attribute, the bars are sorted correctly. The code without color:

```py
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df, x='value', y='name', orientation='h')
fig.show()
```

The output is just as expected:

[image: Bars are sorted in descending order]

However, when I add the color attribute, the bars get sorted by the color:

```py
fig = px.bar(data, x='value', y='name', orientation='h', color='group')
fig.show()
```

The bars get a different sorting:
[image: The bars are grouped by colors]

Is there a way to prevent this behavior of grouping of bars? I am using plotly version 4.1.1 with python 3.7. I want the bars sorted like the first code block but colored by the group column.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your options here would be to either provide the desired ordering explicitly in `category_orders` e.g. `category_orders=dict(group=["Tokyo", "Delhi", ...])` or if what you're after is simply to order them by value you can use set the Y-axis category order to be dynamic with `fig.update_layout(yaxis_categoryorder = 'total ascending')`

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought you were wrong and then noticed I am using wrong axis :) BTW the docs are here https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-categoryorder